# Custom ListView with image, text and add item button

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I am quite new to Android and can't achieve this, been searching all day.

[Layout I'm trying to create.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyWmb.png)

I have created the custom xml layout, I have found ways to add items on create, but I need the list to be empty and than when the button is pressed to add from a list.

This is the layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/info_img_view"
android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_time_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="right"
        />

</TableRow>
```

I have a ListView in the main activity:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

How do I go about this? I would appreciate it if someone can point me to a resource where I can learn what the code is actually doing, not the tutorials I find where I just copy and paste...

Thanks!

**Edit, a bit more explanation of what I'm trying to achieve**

I have 6 buttons. When a button is pressed it should add a list item with two textviews, and one image out of total three images.

So for instance if Button1 is pressed: Add list item > "Text one" "Text one" "imageTwoOfThree".

Than, if Button2 is pressed: Add list item on top > "Text two" "Text two" "imageTwoOfThree"

And so on... The text is hardcoded.

Comment: can you just post your java class

Comment: Instead of using Table layout use Linear Layout that way it'll be easy. and for the functionality you're looking for just set your Listview adaptor on that button click. Since you don't want the code so try it

Comment: @quicklearner I have nothing in the java class...

Comment: @sumit I could do that, I need the code but I thought it would be nice if someone could explain it at least a bit...

Comment: have a look at it it's a nice tutorial explaining everything in detail : http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/
Let me know if you are stuck somewhere

Comment: 1. What you need to do is make a layout resource file which is the layout for one single row. 
2. Then it would be better if you make a class which stores the details of the objects you will be adding to the list. 
3. Now you also need a custom adapter which will link the list with the data.

Comment: @sumit Ok, I seriously can't wrap my head around this... I'm trying all day long, to no avail. I've updated my question to better explain what I'm trying to achieve... Help is VERY appreciated now! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here use this:
I have created a list with dummydata you can change the text and Image according to you

First create a class Data:

```
public class Data {

    private String name,price;
    private int imageId;
    public Data(){}

    public Data(String name,String price,int imageId){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
}
```

Then create a ListView Adapter to handle your data:

```
public class ListViewAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewAdaptor.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Data> mDataList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView name,price;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            price= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }

    public ListViewAdaptor(List<Data> dataList){
        this.mDataList = dataList;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Data data = mDataList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(data.getName());
        holder.price.setText(data.getPrice());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(data.getImageId());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataList.size();
    }
}
```

layout for your list view items name it list_view_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:text="name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:text="price"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then from your activity where you want to add listView add recyclerView in layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Then use this recyclerview like this:
//I have called it from my MainActivity you can use it in whatever activity you'll like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ListViewAdaptor mAdapter;
    private List<Data> mDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new ListViewAdaptor(mDataList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        prepareList();
    }

    public void prepareList(){
       Data data = new Data("Item1","Price1",R.drawable.star);
        mDataList.add(data);
        data = new Data("Item2","Price2",R.drawable.star);
        mDataList.add(data);
        data = new Data("Item3","Price3",R.drawable.star);
        mDataList.add(data);
        data = new Data("Item4","Price4",R.drawable.star);
        mDataList.add(data);
        data = new Data("Item5","Price5",R.drawable.star);
        mDataList.add(data);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! I did some heavy changes, but now I know exactly what I was doing wrong. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You will find lots of online resources for this. But let me put it in a brief way.
Assuming you want to store 2 textviews in one single row.
1. For each layout of the row, you will need to make a custom layout xml file and design your layout there.

2. Next, make a class which stores the data and returns the data through getters.

   ```
   class Category {
   private String categoryName;
   private String categoryImageURL;

   Category (String categoryName, String categoryImageUrl) {
       this.categoryName = categoryName;
       this.categoryImageURL = categoryImageUrl;
   }
   String getCategoryName () {
       return categoryName;
   }
   String getCategoryImageURL () {
       return categoryImageURL;
   }
   }
   ```
3. Now make a custom arrayadapter which will link the data and the layout.
   Extend the arrayadapter class with the class you defined above.

   ```
   private class categoryArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {
   private Context context;
   private List<Category> categories;

   public categoryArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Category> objects) {
       super(context, resource, objects);

       this.context = context;
       this.categories = objects;
   }

   public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       Category category = categories.get(position);

       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View           view     = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_row_view, null);

       TextView  categoryListRowText  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.categoryListRowText);
       TextView  categoryListRowImage    = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.categoryListRowImage);

       categoryListRowText.setText(category.getCategoryName());
       categoryListRowImage.setText(category.getCategoryImageURL());

       return view;
   }
   }
   ```
4. Finally link the adapter to your listview

   ```
   ArrayAdapter<Category> adapter = new categoryArrayAdapter(this, 0, categories);
   categoryListView.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```

Hope this answered you question.