# Create Custom listview with two textviews and two Buttons

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a custom listview in which 2 buttons and two  textviews. Like this[(Image of List view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6PSp.png). When user click on these buttons then status is changed to particular user.
Click on Approve then Status is changed as Approved
Click on Disapprove Status is changed as Disapproved
 My database structure is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJVS4.png)
I check all examples here but these are not enough to create this type of list.

Comment: i recommend use Recyclerview instead of listview

Comment: You need to create custom adapter for that
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: follow this link : http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here have a look at my other answer just change the parameters according to you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44492259/7290822

and use this layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/row_selector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/rowLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="Name: Tahir"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:text="Approve"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:background="#e2e2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:text="Disapprove"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#ed1c24"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if you stuck somewhere.
Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks alot bro..Can you tell me if i have two textboxes first is for name and second for user id. how to set user name and id on these textboxes.
User id and name is retrieved from firebase database

Comment: see this line I am sending my list of type data to the listview adapter class mAdapter = new ListViewAdaptor(mDataList); you have to store your data in mDataList and then in adapter class 
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Data data = mDataList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(data.getName());
        holder.price.setText(data.getPrice());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(data.getImageId());
    }
retrieve the data and set it

Comment: if you need only two fields you can remove the third field from data class and make necessary changes